# Modsecurity Encrypted traffic in 3 tier architecture

Tags: encryption, web-application, apache, mod-security

The scenario is that we have 3 tier architecture DMZ > BEA > DB with end to end encryption the data is encrypted within DMZ > BEA > DB.

I have read that modsecurity doest deal with encrypted traffic it is positioned in Apache in a way that after mod_ssl decrypts the traffic, modsecurity analyze the un-encrypted traffic.

Now after modsecurity analyze the decrypted traffic, in three tier arch it will be passed to BEA, now will that traffic be encrypted? Like after modsecurity does its thing, will that traffic again pass through mod_ssl to encrypt and send to BEA or it will be send directly to BEA after modsecurity as unencrypted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on your configuration and your wishes.

Your setup certainly *could* re-encrypt  after analyzing with mod_security and before forwarding to your application server. You would do so by using the `ProxyPassReverse` and `SSLProxyEngine` configuration options - see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/84821/apache-proxypass-with-ssl) for an example.

So that begs the question: *should* you use TLS between your webserver and your application server?

To answer this question you'll need to assess your network and determine if you actually trust it sufficiently to retransmit your requests in the clear.